# Error in ToggleButton ListView

Tags: android, listview, toggle, android-arrayadapter, togglebutton

I have a `listView` and there has a `toggleButton` in `listView`. Whenever I click the first row toggleButton, the ninth row toggleButton will be clicked also. When I scroll down then up again, the first toggleButton become unclicked but the second and tenth toggleButton be clicked. It really strange !

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_to_do, null);
            holder= new ViewHolder();
            holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.task_title);
            holder.time = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.time);
            holder.date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);
            final ToggleButton toggle =(ToggleButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.donePic);
            toggle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if (toggle.isChecked()) {

                        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Clicked Laugh Vote", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Not Clicked Laugh Vote", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        holder.text.setText(search.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.time.setText(search.get(position).getTime());
        holder.date.setText(search.get(position).getDate());
        return convertView;
    }
```

Anyone knows where did the error came from ?

Comment: You may take a look on my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39926388/spannable-string-only-working-for-last-item-in-listview/39950834#39950834. It should be helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1: Your toggle button must be in holder.

```
holder.toggle = (ToggleButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.toggle);
```

2: In `onClick` when you check if it's clicked or not, you must save it in your `search` list as well.

```
holder.toggle.setChecked(search.get(position).isChecked())
```

The `isChecked()` method indicate whether the toggle button is checked or not. For this you must define a field in your list items and save for each item the status of toggle button.

**Update 1:**

Lets say you have a class named `MyObject` and you have a list of them in your adapter. You defined your like this: `List<MyObject> search = new ArrayList<MyObject>();` and your `MyObject` class is like this:

```
public class MyObject {

    private String title;
    private String time;
    private String date;
    private boolean checked;

    public String getTitle(){
        return title;
    }

    public String getDate(){
        return date;
    }

    public String getTime(){
        return time;
    }

    public boolean isChecked(){
        return checked;
    }
    public void setChecked(boolean val){
        this.checked = val;
    }
}
```

Now every time you click and change the toggle you must call `setChecked` on that item position (instead of showing toast) and then when you want to re-create items, you must call `holder.toggle.setChecked(search.get(position).isChecked())`

I hope it help you

Comment: You must write this method in your Object if you defined `search` list like this: `List<Object>`

Comment: I don't get it :(

Answer (score 0):

It happens because ListView recycles views. You need always set ToggleButton status, also when ToggleButton shouldn't be checked.

```
toggle.setChecked(isShouldBeChecked);
```

You can create an boolean array, which contains status of every ToggleButton. If user checks some button, then update his status in the array.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the ListView is not getting the **position** of the button pressed my guess is to save **the position of the button pressed in the listView**

```
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {



                   //save the tag of the pressed button as position
                    position = (int)v.getTag();

                    if (toggle.isChecked()) {

                        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Clicked Laugh Vote", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Not Clicked Laugh Vote", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
```

and pass it to the **holder**

```
holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        holder.text.setText(search.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.time.setText(search.get(position).getTime());
        holder.date.setText(search.get(position).getDate());
        return convertView;
```