# Android Plus & Minus buttons are not working correctly in Listview with Baseadapter

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview with a custom Row.xml .

2 Textviews 
2 Buttons

The Buttons function are **Plus and Minus Quantity**. When the App run at the start, each row **Default quantity is 1**.

When clicking on the Plus, quantity + 1

When clicking on the Minus Button, quantity -1

[image]

From screenshot 1 to screenshot 2 is working correctly. I click Plus button 4 times for Row 1(data1).

**However, if I click on 2nd Row(data2) Plus Button, the quantity didn't Plus 1 but straight away jump to 6. This bug also apply to Minus as well**

**So that means the Quantity is not unique in each Row. Instead, it accumulate both rows Quantity together.**

**MainActivity**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final ArrayList arrayList=new ArrayList<String>();
    arrayList.add("data1");
    arrayList.add("data2");

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    final MyCustomAdapter myCustomAdapter=new MyCustomAdapter(this,arrayList);
    listView.setAdapter(myCustomAdapter);
```

**MyCustomAdapter.java**

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

int ab=1;
int p=1;
Context ctx;
LayoutInflater inflater=null;

ArrayList arrayList;

public MyCustomAdapter(Context ctx,ArrayList arrayList){
    this.ctx=ctx;
    this.arrayList=arrayList;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return arrayList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return arrayList.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    View row=view;
    if(row==null){
        inflater=(LayoutInflater)ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row,null);
    }

    TextView product_name=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.text);
    product_name.setText(arrayList.get(i).toString());
    final TextView quantity=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
    Button minus=(Button) row.findViewById(R.id.minus);
    Button plus=(Button) row.findViewById(R.id.plus);

    minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            if(ab!=1){  // if quantity =1, cannot minus anymore
                ab=ab-1;
            }
            p=ab;
            quantity.setText(Integer.toString(ab));
        }
    });

    plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            ab=ab+1;
            p=ab;
            quantity.setText(Integer.toString(ab));
        }
    });
    return row;
}
}
```

Anyone know how to fix this bug?

Comment: put debug on button click listener and check what value assign to int ab

Comment: @DaminiMehra I put 2 Logs for  ab, the values are same as it shows on the screen.

Comment: I think you have something wrong in creating your data list. You only have one field [String] in the array, so how to seperately have the quantity of different item? You may take a look on the answer that I posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39926388/spannable-string-only-working-for-last-item-in-listview/39950834#39950834, I think that will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a class variable ab, you should cast your quantity.getText () to int.
So create variable

```
int mQuantity = Integer.valueOf (quantity.geText().toString ())
```

Then do transform this variable adding one and reset Textview value.

Also make sure there is a value in Textview quantity and that you won't get a parse NumberException

In your case for minus exemple :

```
...
Button plus=(Button) row.findViewById(R.id.plus);
int mQuantity = Integer.valueOf(quantity.getText().toString());

    minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            if(mQuantity!=1){  // if quantity =1, cannot minus anymore
                mQuantity += 1;
            }
            p=mQuantity;
            quantity.setText(Integer.toString(mQuantity));
        }
    });
```

Comment: i getting confuse by ur answer

Answer (score 0):

In your *clickListener* use values from corresponding textviews
In your minus ClickListener

```
if (Integer.parseInt(quantity.getText().toString())!=1){
    quantity.setText(""+Integer.parseInt(quantity.getText().toString())-1);
}
```

In your plus ClickListener

```
if (Integer.parseInt(quantity.getText().toString())!=1){
    quantity.setText(""+Integer.parseInt(quantity.getText().toString())+1);
}
```

Comment: If i dont declare Global, but put it inside getview method, it shows an error " Transforms variables into final one element array"

Comment: Your answer is not working. All the buttons didn't respond when clicking

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem solved it myself. I used objects to populate children of ExpandableListView which contain plus and minus button like your scenario. I found that you need to update the objects inside the OnClick Listeners or they will increment based on the global variable value.
Here is the code:

```
public class MainListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter 
implements View.OnClickListener {
private Context context;
private List<Category> expandableListTitle;
private HashMap<Category, List<Item>> expandableListDetail;
private double quant;
public MainListAdapter(Context context, List<Category> 
 expandableListTitle,
                                   HashMap<Category, List<Item>> 
 expandableListDetail) {
    this.context = context;
    this.expandableListTitle = expandableListTitle;
      this.expandableListDetail = expandableListDetail;
}

   @Override
   public Object getChild(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) 
{
    return 


   this.expandableListDetail.get
    (this.expandableListTitle.get(listPosition))
            .get(expandedListPosition);
}




@Override
public long getChildId(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) {
    return expandedListPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int listPosition, final int expandedListPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final Item expandedListitem = (Item) getChild(listPosition, expandedListPosition);
    Log.d("item", expandedListitem.getQuantity()+expandedListitem.getItemName());

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }

    String nam=expandedListitem.getItemName();
    Button plus = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.plus);
    Button minus = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.minus);
    final TextView quantity = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.quantity);
  //First get the quantity from object 

  quant=expandedListitem.getQuantity();

    quantity.setText(String.valueOf(quant));
    plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
  //also each time button is clicked get and set values to objects     
       quant=expandedListitem.getQuantity();
            quant+=1;
            Log.d("clicked",String.valueOf(quant));
            expandedListitem.setQuantity(quant);
            quantity.setText(String.valueOf(quant));
        }
    });
    minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            quant=expandedListitem.getQuantity();
            quant-=1;

               expandedListitem.setQuantity(quant);
               quantity.setText(String.valueOf(quant));

           }
    });


    TextView name =(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_text);
    name.setText(nam);
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int listPosition) {
    return this.expandableListDetail.get(this.expandableListTitle.get(listPosition))
            .size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int listPosition) {
    return this.expandableListTitle.get(listPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this.expandableListTitle.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int listPosition) {
    return listPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int listPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Category category = (Category) getGroup(listPosition);
    String name=category.getCategoryName();
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.
                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.category, null);
    }
    TextView listTitleTextView = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.cat_text);
    listTitleTextView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);

    listTitleTextView.setText(name);
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

}
```