# Android: Identify listviewItem when checkbox of item is checked/unchecked

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I got a listView with dynamically created items. Each item has a checkbox which can be checked/unchecked. When the checkbox is pressed this function is called:

```
public void updateClientList(View v) {
}
```

Now I want to change the specific item in my arraylist which is the base of the listview. But how do I know which checkbox was checked?

How can I do that? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Take a look on my answer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39926388/spannable-string-only-working-for-last-item-in-listview/39950834#comment67264957_39950834. It may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have a checkbox, you can use the OnItemClick listener that gives you position besides the view, but with this solution you have to update the checkbox manually so it doesnt consume the item click.

Another way is to use setTag(position) on the views you supply when binding.

You should consider moving on to RecyclerView.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html

Comment: How can I address the checkbox in the onitemclick listener?

Comment: You don't. The adapter should be the only one addressing the checkbox. That's the idea of listviews(and recyclerview) you don't control the views from the outside, only from the adapter. The list has some data array associated to it, thats where you set the checkbox state (isChecked T or F)