# How can I get the n-th element in a ListView

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

I have a listView with two items inside each row, a TextView and a Switch button.

This is how I created the List View:

```
rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_view, container,false);

ListView list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listViewFragment);

rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonSubmitPlayersTrainingAttendances) ;

String[] from = { "namePlayer", "switch" };
int[] to = { R.id.textViewPlayerName, R.id.switchAttendance };
List<HashMap<String,String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();


for(int a=0; a < totalPlayers ;a++)
{
HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
             hm.put("namePlayer", playersSurnames.get(a) + " " + playersNames.get(a) );
             aList.add(hm);        
    }


SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.player_list, from, to);       
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I used the layout fragment_list_view.xml which has the listView and then in the SimpleAdapter I used a List>  (aList) and the layout player_list.xml which has a TextView and a Switch. I don’t know if it is the right way to do this but it works.

**fragment_list_view.xml**

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
</ListView>
```

**player_list.xml**

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewPlayerName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="TextView" />

<Switch
        android:id="@+id/switchAttendance"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

As you can see the ListView works and I see on the screen what I want : the list of the players  and the switches for each player:

Screenshot --> [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyrx0.jpg)

Now, if I do a getItem() from the adapter I see the first element of the row (Player1, Player2,...)

My question is: how can I get the Switch Id of each row (each player)  to see if it’s checked or not? And if I did the ListView in the wrong way can you explain me what is the best way to do that?
Thank you

Comment: you need to make an object for each player instead of the complex nested hashmaps, in this object you will have player properties (name, id, status, ...) in the adapter use the List<Player> to populate the list and based on `boolean status` you decide if it's On or Off, and when you `getItem()` it will return a `player` you can check `Player#getStatus()` to find if On or Off, AND when switch is clicked you need to update that list of players (objects) to `setStatus()` based on switch button status.

Comment: Yes, I used a  custom SimpleAdapter instead of the HashMap and it worked well, thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look of my answer to this, [Spannable String only working for last Item in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39926388/spannable-string-only-working-for-last-item-in-listview/39950834#comment67264957_39950834).

You can replace that ArrayAdapter with SimpleAdapter, like this:

```
    String[] from = {ITEM_ID, ITEM_NAME, ITEM_CHECKED};
    int[] to = {R.id.tvId, R.id.tvDescription, R.id.cb};
    mSimpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mDataList, R.layout.custom_list_items, from, to){
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // Prepare views ready for data
            convertView = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cb);
            TextView tvDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);

            cb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    CheckBox buttonView = (CheckBox) view;
                    // Get view, position and DataList(position)
                    int pos = (int) buttonView.getTag();
                    HashMap<String, Object> selectedItem = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                    selectedItem = (HashMap<String, Object>) getItem(pos);

                    // Update DataList
                    mDataList.remove(selectedItem);
                    selectedItem.remove(ITEM_CHECKED);
                    if(buttonView.isChecked()){
                        selectedItem.put(ITEM_CHECKED, true);
                        mDataList.add(pos, selectedItem);
                    }else{
                        selectedItem.put(ITEM_CHECKED, false);
                        mDataList.add(pos, selectedItem);
                    }

                    // Update all UI views by
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+pos+" Changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
            // Get data from DataList
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            HashMap<String, Object> currentItem = (HashMap<String, Object>) getItem(position);
            toggleLineThrough(tvDescription, (String)currentItem.get(ITEM_NAME), (boolean)currentItem.get(ITEM_CHECKED));

            // Save position to CheckBox, so position can be retrieved when CheckBox is clicked
            cb.setTag(position);

            return convertView;
        }
    };
    mListView.setAdapter(mSimpleAdapter);
```

Hope that help!